# How do I retrieve coordinates information from fusion table

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I am developing a webpage where I am using google map with county boundaries within U.S and allow user to place marker on it. I am currently using polygon data from  https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=0IMZAFCwR-t7jZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjIxMDIxNw, and now I would like to retrieve all coordinates for one specific county. e.g., a user places a marker on King County,WA, and the user would like to retrieve and store its associated coordinates. From the online fusion table, a column called geometry, which contains all coordinates information respect to a specific county, but how do I retrieve that piece of information?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the google API docs. You will likely need to request the table and then parse the json to find the county you are looking for. From there you can get the geometry field from the column.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/column/get